# twig defined how to present in the view

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I have an array which looks like so ---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Category ID
            [1] => Category
            [2] => Country
            [3] => Sale price
            [4] => Price
            [5] => Currency
            [6] => VAT
            [7] => Product name
            [8] => Description
            [9] => product-image-1-url
            [10] => SKU
            [11] => Stock
            [12] => Variation name
            [13] => PropertyName
            [14] => PropertyValue
        )

)
```

So when i am trying to show it in my twig file show should i suppose to view it !

```
{% for label in labelsUnq%} 
    <thead>
    <td>
        {%if label is defined %} {{label}}{% endif %}                                      
    </td> 
    </thead>
```

So what should i write here `{{label}}` to show the all values from that array, anyone knows how to solve this problem !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two for loops:

```
{% for array in labelsUnq%}
    {% for value in array %} 
        ...
            {{label}}                                      
        ...
    {% enfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the code you're looking for (I also moved the `<thead>` tag out of the loop):

```
<thead>
{% for key,value in labelsUnq %}
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</thead>
```

More info can be found in the [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable).